# Unable to sort a column in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs, azure-active-directory

I am trying to sort the 'device' column alphabetically in the table. I am new to react and found this approach for sorting in react. Where is the mistake?

```
function createData(videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite) {
return { videos, status, model, manage, device, favourite };
}
const rows = [
createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Cam1', true),
createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Offline', 2, 37, 'Am2', true),
createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 24, 'Zam3', false),
createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug50zmP9I7s", 'Offline', 2, 67, 'Dam4', false),
createData("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8", 'Online', 2, 49, 'Lam5', false),
];
```

This is the sorting logic that I am using for sorting

```
export default function StreamPage(props) {
    const [sortType, setSortType] = React.useState('device');
    const [Results, setResults] = React.useState(rows);
    const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = React.useState("DESC"); 
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const sortArray = () => {
          const types = {
            device: 'device',
          };
      let type ='device';
      const sortProperty = types[type];
      const sorted = [...rows].sort((a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]);
      console.log(sorted); // sorted is not giving the sorted column here 
      setResults(sorted);
    };
```

This is my return function

```
 return(
    <div onClick={setSortType} className="div">
        <div class="info">
            {sortDirection === "ASC" ? (
                <KeyboardArrowUpIcon fontSize='small' />
            ) : (
                    <KeyboardArrowDownIcon fontSize='small' />
                )

            }
        </div>
   );}
```

Comment: const sorted = [...rows].sort((a, b) => b()[sortProperty] - a()[sortProperty]); Might this work? I think you need to execute each row or else it is trying to sort the function?

Comment: Thank you very much James for responding but as the column has strings therefore localeCompare fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the String **`localeCompare()`** method since you are comparing String properties.

```
const sorted = [...rows].sort((a, b) => a[sortProperty].localeCompare(b[sortProperty]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ray. You are right for string comparison localeCompare is the correct approach. Cheers

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the change dependency to your useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ....
    ....
}, [sortProperty]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. localeCompare for column sorting fixed my issue.